# CanCan abilities and additional rules by engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have application and engines (gems, Rails::Engine).
CanCan used for authorization and I want to use it at engines.
Engines isolated with namespace, but for example:

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
  end
end
```

So, I can use load_and_authorize_resource at controllers (must specify model class name) and 'can' helper also. All abilities I must write to Ability at main application (models from engines must be namespaced). It is not nice way. I want specify abilities for engine at this engine, but without create new ability object.
How can I do this? Any idea?

Comment: One of solution: make `MyEngine::Ability` class at engine as model (`include ::CanCan::Ability` also) and write abilities for engine here. Than add `before_filter` to `ApplicationController` which make `current_ability.merge(MyEngine::Ability.new(current_user))`. Maybe it is what I want...

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't super pretty, but I did something similar with a Rails application I'm writing currently. I have written my own engine inside this application called FormX, which is sort of a form CMS engine. I wanted users to have the ability to only edit certain responses to forms, and only some users to have the ability to create forms.

Given that I had a `Form` model in the `Formx` namespace, I was able to define abilities in my MainApp `ability.rb` file by doing using `Formx::Form` syntax.

Ex.

```
can :manage, Formx::Form
```

Then in my controller I had to manually place the `authorize!` calls in each action, as I couldn't get `load_and_authorize_resource` to work within the engine's namespace.

Comment: Try use `load_and_authorize_resource class: Form`, it work with engine namespace.